# Facing flutter plugin issue

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add **flutter_svg: ^0.5.1** in my project pubspec.yaml and facing following issue.

depends on flutter_svg >=0.0.2 which requires Flutter SDK version >=0.3.6 <2.0.0, version solving failed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like this to override the dependency:

`dependency_overrides:
  flutter_svg: '0.5.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Open the flutter_console.bat (on window) or flutter_console.sh (on linux) file from your downloaded root flutter folder. This should bring up a terminal running Flutter locally.

Now type `flutter upgrade`
This should resolve your issue considering its a version compatibility issue.